# Maximum value of tns:intGTE1 data type for simpleUploadAPI in files-config.xml of HCL Connections 6.5.1

Tags: xml, types, xsd, ibm-connections, hcl-connections

I want to increase the maximum upload file size of HCL Connections 6.5.1. It is configured in `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/config/cells/CnxCell/LotusConnections-config/files-config.xml`

```
<simpleUploadAPI maximumSizeInKb="8388608">
    <organization estimatedBytesInSeconds="8388608" id="admin_replace" maxConcurrenceRequests="50" maximumSizeInKb="512000"/>
</simpleUploadAPI>
```

But this seems invalid, the files app won't properly load any more:

[image]

So I checked the corresponding xsd validation file about the maximum value here:

```
   <xsd:element name="simpleUploadAPI">
                <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="organization" type="tns:organization" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                        </xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:attribute name="maximumSizeInKb" type="tns:intGTE1" use="required"/>
                </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
```

I don't know what the type `intGTE1` means. The scheme definition in the head of the document refers to two links:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://www.ibm.com/connections/files/files-config/1.0"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.ibm.com/connections/files/files-config/1.0"
    xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
    <!-- ... -->
```

Since both IBM links were deleted(redirecting to the IBM homepage), how is it possible to know what's the limit? I know that files over 500MB [should be handled by IHS](https://help.hcltechsw.com/connections/v65/admin/install/t_install_post_files_uploads.html), it's a test environment to try this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know how to get the definition of that XML type in general. But I found out that [using the `FilesConfigService`](https://help.hcltechsw.com/connections/v65/admin/admin/t_admin_files_changing_config_properties.html) with checking the config file out and in, there is some logic validating the provided scheme type:

```
wsadmin>FilesConfigService.checkInConfig()
Using configuration arguments :
        workingDirectory: /tmp/files
        cellName: CnxCell
        nodeName: None
        serverName: None
Loading schema file for validation: /tmp/files/files-config.xsd
Exception - org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-maxInclusive-valid: Value '8388608' is not facet-valid with respect to maxInclusive '2097152' for type 'intGTE2M'.
Exception - org.xml.sax.SAXParseException org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-maxInclusive-valid: Value '8388608' is not facet-valid with respect to maxInclusive '2097152' for type 'intGTE2M'.
```

So the maximum possible value is **2097152**, which equals to 2GB.